# VLookup in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet, vlookup

I'm trying to create a userform, where the users can enter a batch number and when they hit OK a VLOOKUP function will give them the information they need. However, the target data is on two different sheets (e.g., sheet1 and sheet2).

I've managed to create the VBA below, but it only works for sheet1. And if a wrong batch is entered, no result or msgbox is shown.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo myerrorhandler

Dim Batch As Long
Dim Result
Dim Result2
Dim Target1 As Range
Dim Target2 As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet

Batch = TextBox1.text

Set Target1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("C7:ZZ10000")
Set Target2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("C7:ZZ1000")


Result = vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target1, 1, False)
Result = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target1, 17, False)
Result = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target1, 18, False)
Result = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target1, 20, False)

If Result > 0 Then
MsgBox "Batch details:" & vbNewLine & Result

ElseIf Result = 0 Then

Result2 = vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target2, 1, False)
Result2 = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target2, 17, False)
Result2 = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target2, 18, False)
Result2 = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target2, 20, False)

If Result > 0 Then
MsgBox "Batch details:" & vbNewLine & Result2

ElseIf Result2 = 0 Then
MsgBox "Not present, or wrong entry"


End If
End If
Exit Sub


myerrorhandler:
If Err.Number = 13 Then
MsgBox "Invalid value"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was your tests in the `If`, `Result` is a string and the test `Result > 0` isn't meaningful.

As you add 8 characters (`Batch :` + new line) at each call (4) of `Result`, what you meant by `Result > 0` is actually `Len(Result) > 32`.

This should be closer of what you are trying to achieve :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo myerrorhandler
Dim Batch As Long
Dim Result
Dim Result2
Dim Target1 As Range
Dim Target2 As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Batch = TextBox1.Text
Set Target1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("C7:ZZ10000")
Set Target2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("C7:ZZ1000")

Result = vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target1, 1, False)
Result = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target1, 17, False)
Result = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target1, 18, False)
Result = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target1, 20, False)

If Len(Result) > 32 Then
    MsgBox "Batch details:" & vbNewLine & Result
ElseIf Len(Result) = 32 Then
    Result2 = vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target2, 1, False)
    Result2 = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target2, 17, False)
    Result2 = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target2, 18, False)
    Result2 = Result & vbNewLine & "Batch: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Batch, Target2, 20, False)

    If Len(Result2) > 32 Then
        MsgBox "Batch details:" & vbNewLine & Result2
    ElseIf Len(Result2) = 32 Then
        MsgBox "Not present, or wrong entry"
    End If
End If
Exit Sub

myerrorhandler:
    If Err.Number = 13 Then MsgBox "Invalid value"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your code gives the same results as my code does. The result of VLOOKUP (Result and result2) are text. VLOOKUP in sheet 2 doesn't appear to take place.

Comment: Did you tried to place breakpoints to see where the code is going with the tests? If you don't know how to debbug efficiently in VBA, take a look at these : excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html and excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel , it'll save you hours of coderage ;)